# wp7 handling application bar button click dynamically in pivots

Tags: windows-phone

i have a pivot page with 3 pages and there are two application bar buttons. But i want that when pivot is changed, the first button of application bar should do different tasks on different pivot, and second button will do same task on all pivots. I am doing this as:

private void PivotControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ApplicationBarIconButton firstButton = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];

```
        if (PivotControl.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {               
            firstButton.IsEnabled = true;
            firstButton.Click += new EventHandler(FirstPivotButton_Click);
        }
        else if (PivotControl.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            firstButton.IsEnabled = true;
            firstButton.Click += new EventHandler(SecondPivotButton_Click);

        }
        else if (PivotControl.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            firstButton.IsEnabled = false;                
        }
  }

    void FirstPivotButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PageA.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    void SecondPivotButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PageB.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

But the problem is that PageA is being navigated well but there is problem in going to PageB from secondpivotbutton click event. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use this great library for simplifying usage of ApplicationBar on Windows Phone - [**AppBarUtils**](http://appbarutils.codeplex.com/).
You can find them on [NuGet as well](http://nuget.org/packages/AppBarUtils/).

There is also nice tutorial, how ti display different buttons for each panorama/pivot item using this library:
http://allenlooplee.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/how-to-show-different-app-bar-for-different-pivotpano-item/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did this in one of my apps. Button 1 is different for pivot pages and button 2 is always the same, just like you.

On the SelectionChanged event, update the button icon uri and text:

```
Private Sub statPivot_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles statPivot.SelectionChanged
        Dim saveBtn As ApplicationBarIconButton = ApplicationBar.Buttons(0)

        If statPivot.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            'calculation pane active
            saveBtn.Text = "save"
            saveBtn.IconUri = New Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.save.rest.png", UriKind.Relative)
        Else
            'history pane active
            saveBtn.Text = "clear"
            saveBtn.IconUri = New Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.refresh.rest.png", UriKind.Relative)
        End If
    End Sub
```

then in the onclick event I detect the pivot pane that's being viewed and use a basic if...then...else... to run the different code within the same handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamically change app bar buttons at run time you can do this:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="appbar1" IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abMain1" IconUri="/icons/appbar.favs.addto.rest.png" Text="blabla1"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>

    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="appbar2" IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abMain2" IconUri="/icons/appbar.favs.addto.rest.png" Text="blabla2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="abMain3" IconUri="/icons/appbar.cancel.rest.png" Text="blabla3"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And then change it from code:

```
 ApplicationBar = (Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar) Resources["appbar1"];
```

and

```
 ApplicationBar = (Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar) Resources["appbar2"];
```

You can big numbers of different `AppBars`. 
Hope its help.